# How to define the descriminator column as ENUM for Class Table Inheritance in Doctrine's?

Tags: mysql, inheritance, enums, doctrine-orm, class-table-inheritance

I want to implement the [Class Table Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance):

```
/**
 * Foo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="foos", ...)
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "bar" = "Bar",
 *     "buz" = "Buz"
 * })
 */
abstract class Foo
{
    ...
}
```

Since I run the "code first" approach, the database is generated by Doctrine:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
$ bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

The discriminator column `foos.type` gets the type `VARCHAR(255)`. I want it to get an `ENUM` instead.

**How to define the annotation for the entity class for getting an `ENUM` discriminator?**

Comment: Once again, editing the schema file is the only way I found.  Does not really matter.  You have no access to it via the orm anyways.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database

Answer (score 1):

It works with `columnDefinition="ENUM('bar', 'buz')"`:

```
/**
 * Foo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="foos", ...)
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('bar', 'buz')")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "bar" = "Bar",
 *     "buz" = "Buz"
 * })
 */
abstract class Foo
{
    ...
}
```

---

Unfortunately it causes an annoying side effect (s. also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937197/how-to-get-doctrine-handling-enums-correctly)): The migration mechanism of Doctrine seems to handle `ENUM`s incorrectly. The `doctrine:migrations:diff` command creates a migration like this:

```
final class Version20180619205625 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE foos CHANGE type `type` ENUM(\'bar\', \'buz\')');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE tasks CHANGE `type` type VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
    }
}
```

I execute it, the `type` column become an `ENUM`. But a new executing of `doctrine:migrations:diff` creates a migration with the same content again... Means, Doctrine "thinks", the column is still `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late answer, but the solution is to register a custom mapping type which will actually use ENUM on database side. Most simply:

```
class YourType extends Type
{
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        return 'ENUM(\'one\', \'two\')';
    }
}
```

register it in your Doctrine config under some `your_type` name and use:

```
 @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="your_type")
```

This field will be NOT NULL by default. In case of mysql, it'll use first value from ENUM as default, like a "implicit default"